# When syncing my model within Invantive Control for Excel I get the error "Could not find parameter with name 'P_SCHEME_CODE'

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

When I try to synchronise my model retrieving GL Account Classification information from Exact Online, I get the following error:

itgensdf031: Could not find parameter with name 'P_SCHEME_CODE':

[image]

What should I change in order for this to work?

Related SQL query on Exact Online table `GLAccountClassifications`:

```
select division_code
,      glclassification_code_attr
,      glaccount_code_attr
from   glaccountclassifications
where  glaccountscheme_code_attr = :P_SCHEME_CODE
order
by     glaccount_code_attr
,      division_code
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL query you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query listed uses `:P_SCHEME_CODE`. For SQL this would work, but Invantive Control parses the query early to retrieve the list of fields from the metadata. It needs to know the parameters and find values for them in the Invantive Control list of parameters as defined in the Model Editor under "Parameters" in the tree.

In Invantive Control to use a parameter in a query you will need to use `$P{P_SCHEME_CODE}` instead of `:P_SCHEME_CODE`.
`$P{P_SCHEME_CODE}` can be inserted in a query by hand or by using Building Blocks drop down and then choosing a previously defined parameter.